# Properties of derivative of an integral operator

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, functions

I have the following simple integral operator $$ \lambda_y K_yf_y=f_y.$$ The operator $K$ is indexed by a real parameter $y$. Then I am interested in the properties of $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}K$. I hence write as follows:
\begin{align}
\Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}K_y\Big)f_y&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{K_{y+h}f_y-K_yf_y}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{K_{y+h}(f_y+f_{y+h}-f_{y+h})-K_yf_y}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{K_{y+h}f_{y+h}-K_yf_y}{h}-\lim_{h\to0}\frac{K_{y+h}(f_y-f_{y+h})}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\frac{1}{\lambda_{y+h}}f_{y+h}-\frac{1}{\lambda_y}f_y}{h}-\lim_{h\to0}\frac{K_{y+h}(f_y-f_{y+h})}{h}\\
&=\frac{1}{\lambda_y}\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\frac{\lambda_y}{\lambda_{y+h}}f_{y+h}-f_y}{h}-\lim_{h\to0}\frac{K_{y+h}(f_y-f_{y+h})}{h}\\
\end{align}

Now it seems quite standard to write $$\frac{1}{\lambda_y}\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\frac{\lambda_y}{\lambda_{y+h}}f_{y+h}-f_y}{h}=\frac{1}{\lambda_y}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f_y$$ and that $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{K_{y+h}(f_y-f_{y+h})}{h}=K_y\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f_y$$ so that

$$\Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}K_y\Big)f_y=\frac{1}{\lambda_y}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f_y-K_y\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f_y$$

Is this alright? to do what I did with all the steps I made? Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you pulled out $\frac{1}{\lambda_y}$ you had $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\frac{f_{y+h}}{\lambda_{y+h}} - \frac{f_y}{\lambda_y}}{h}$$ which you should recognize as $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{f_y}{\lambda_y}$ which is not $\frac{1}{\lambda_y}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f_y$ if $\lambda_y$ is a  function of $y$.

If $\lambda_y$ didn't depend on $y$, your end result would essentially be the product rule.  Just differentiating the original equation and applying the product rule (twice) then solving for $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}K_y$ would be what I would recommend.

Comment: many thanks! :-)